# What is intended browser behaviour in overlaying content on top of scrollbar?

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar, z-index, blogger

Blogger has this new fancy theme that I see a lot of people using, but it seems to me to have an obvious CSS bug as the link gadget overlaps the scrollbar. Are you seeing this problem as well?

[image: Scrollbar being overlapped]

The gadget div has it's CSS set to right:0px and z-index:3000, which causes it to overlap the scrollbar on Chrome for Windows. I would think that browsers shouldn't allow overlapping of scrollbars in the first place? And if they would allow that, isn't it still a usability bug from Google?

UPDATE: Here is a link with a blog where this happens: http://www.judegomila.com/2012/10/how-to-name-your-company.html
And here is the same theme, but without that problem: http://googleblog.blogspot.jp/

Comment: Doh, missed that. Links have been added!

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  have set the `overflow-y` in the `<div class="viewitem-inner">` remove this its on line no 1648

and try the

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;

}
```

also remove the `position:fixed;` from `<div class="viewitem-panel">` on line no 1589

working

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not my own blog, but I have seen numerous links to blogs on Blogger with this problem. I guess that people tend to add or change something in their template, which breaks the behaviour. But this seems to be a possible fix, although Google maybe should see if they could make their theme more fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a usability bug in the Blogger theme. A scrollbar always belongs to some element and elements can be overlapped with other elements – thus the scrollbars could get hidden.